# How to define this decision variable in Gurobi

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

I have a set of pairs of edges (a, b) in E that are given. I want to define a 0-1 decision variable for all a in set A and b (b is different then a) in set A where A is a set of vertices of a graph.

The decision variable should look like this :

```
H[a,b] = 1 if (a,b) is in E 
          0        otherwise
```

This decision variable will be used in some constraints within my mathematical model to test if a given pair of elements say (i,j) -for the sake of simplicity to put it different then the definition above- is in E or not to enforce some behaviour.

I am not sure how to write it in Gurobi using Python API. One naive approach would be to go for:

```
H = {}
for i in SetA:
    for j in SetA:
    H[i, j] = [1 if (i, j) in E else 0]
```

But this way, H is not a Gurobi variable.

Comment: This won't work, as you saw for yourself. Be much more precise where that set E comes from (probably part of other variables; or having H makes not much sense imho) and what i and j  / a and b is as i don't understand your model.

Comment: @sascha I edited my question and clarified that A and B are set of vertices. (a,b) or (i,j) are just indices and pair of vertices.

Comment: This is without context and i don't know what you are really doing. It sounds like the optimization somehow builds the edges of a graph. Then just introduce N binary-decision-vars for all possible N-edges (A, B should be known a-priori; counting and preparing a possibly flat vector of vars can be done in preprocessing). If that's not it; it's probably time for the next edit... But much more precise and bringing more context.

Comment: @sascha I just edited it. I am not aware how to introduce the decision variable. I know how to do it when it comes to a cartesian product but in this situation I ignore how to define it.

Comment: You can always do stuff like ```my_dict[('a','b')] = model.addVar(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, GRB.BINARY, str((a,b))))``` or anything similar. Every container able to store objects can hold your gurobi-vars. Apart from that, i can't help as those edits did not really help to make clear what you are trying to do.